# How can I view the hierarchy of TODO keywords in org agenda mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a variety of (facile) tasks in some kind of hierarchy.

```
* TODO Make a pizza
** TODO Get cheese
*** TODO Buy a cow
** TODO Get tomatoes
*** TODO Grow tomatoes
**** TODO Buy tomatoes
** TODO Buy oven
*** TODO Win Lottery
**** TODO Buy Lottery ticket
```

If I view these in with the org agenda, they're displayed in a flat fashion:

```
  .TODO:    TODO Make a pizza
  .TODO:    TODO Get cheese
  .TODO:    TODO Buy a cow
  .TODO:    TODO Get tomatoes
  .TODO:    TODO Grow tomatoes
  .TODO:    TODO Buy tomatoes
  .TODO:    TODO Buy oven
  .TODO:    TODO Win Lottery
  .TODO:    TODO Buy Lottery ticket
```

I'd like to view these tasks in an indented fashion, so they reflect the dependencies between the tasks. Is this possible / a good idea or am I just using the agenda incorrectly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try customizing `org-agenda-prefix-format`. This can be used to tweak how various kinds of items (including TODOs) are displayed in agenda views.

In particular, you can use `%l` in the `todo` format to prefix the item with a number of spaces corresponding to its level in the hierarchy.

Another option would be to use `%b` to include a 'breadcrumb' trail for each line item showing the hierarchy, e.g. `Level1 -> Level2:  TODO  Do the thing`.

Comment: This works, but sometimes tasks are out of order. I.e, children are not beneath their parents sometimes. This happens if children have a different priority from their parents and can be set via org-agenda-sorting-strategy

Answer (score 4):

The variable `org-tags-match-list-sublevels` can do this:

> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means list also sublevels of headlines matching a search.
>   This variable applies to tags/property searches, and also to stuck
>   projects because this search is based on a tags match as well.
>
> When set to the symbol `indented', sublevels are indented with
>   leading dots.

With `(setq org-tags-match-list-sublevels 'indented)`, a number of dots equal to the level will be prepended to each agenda line to indicate its level.

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the agenda todo view for me (with Org 8.2.10 + Emacs 24.4).

Comment: There are a few agenda buffer producing search functions used by `org-mode` and this variable may not necessarily apply to all of them [I have not tested this] -- the most common search functions are:  `org-agenda-list`; `org-tags-view`; `org-search-view`.

Comment: @glucas You're right, it doesn't work in the global todo list.  It does work in tag and tag-todo searches