# org-agenda tags-todo hierarchy weirdness

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

There's an interesting question about [how to view the hierarchy of TODO keywords in org-agenda](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5900/how-can-i-view-the-hierarchy-of-todo-keywords-in-org-agenda-mode) which shows two different approaches:

- use the `"%l"` specifier in `org-agenda-prefix-format`
- set `org-tags-match-list-sublevels` to `'indentation`

But I can't seem to get either to work.

Using the first method:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %e %l ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels t)))))))
```

I get a backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument buffer-or-string-p 3)
  get-text-property(0 extra-space 3)
  (concat level "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) level))
  (if (equal level "") "" (concat level "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) level)))
  (format "%s" (if (equal level "") "" (concat level "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) level))))
  (format " %s %s %s " (format "%38s" (if (equal breadcrumbs "") "" (concat breadcrumbs "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) breadcrumbs)))) (format "%6s" (if (equal effort "") "" (concat effort "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) effort)))) (format "%s" (if (equal level "") "" (concat level "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) level)))))
  eval((format " %s %s %s " (format "%38s" (if (equal breadcrumbs "") "" (concat breadcrumbs "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) breadcrumbs)))) (format "%6s" (if (equal effort "") "" (concat effort "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) effort)))) (format "%s" (if (equal level "") "" (concat level "" (get-text-property 0 (quote extra-space) level))))))
```

The breadcrumb representation works, but...:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %e %b ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels t)))))))
```

...my headlines are too long and/or nested to neatly fit on the screen using breadcrumbs.

The second method successfully indents the headlines using dots, but it also obliterates the *effort* times with spaces:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %e ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels 'indented)))))))
```

I tried swapping out the *effort* for *breadcrumbs*:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %b ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels 'indented)))))))
```

...and that is *not* obliterated - it shows the breadcrumbs, then indentation dots, then TODO keyword and headline.

Have I just unluckily run into two different bugs or have I done something stupid? I want *mytag* TODOs with effort and indentation.

*GNU Emacs 24.4.1*

*org 8.2.10*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround using the [%(expression) syntax](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/org-agenda-todo-effort-rollup):

```
(defun my-agenda-prefix ()
  (format "%s" (my-agenda-indent-string (org-current-level))))

(defun my-agenda-indent-string (level)
  (if (= level 1)
      ""
    (let ((str ""))
      (while (> level 2)
        (setq level (1- level)
              str (concat str "──")))
      (concat str "►"))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %e %(my-agenda-prefix) ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels t)))))))
```

Not that there is a third bug or oddity here: you can only use %(expression) once, so any other customisations should be added to `my-agenda-prefix`.