# org-agenda todo effort rollup

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

You can use `org-agenda-prefix-format` to have the *effort* shown for each TODO headline:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format " %6e ")))))))
```

Which shows something like:

```
       TODO Some patent task
[0:30] ..TODO Some sub-task
[0:30] ..TODO Some other sub-task
```

Unlike a clocktable the effort of the sub-tasks is not summed up for the parent task. I would like it to look like this:

```
[1:00] TODO Some patent task
[0:30] ..TODO Some sub-task
[0:30] ..TODO Some other sub-task
```

Looking at the documentation for `org-agenda-prefix-format` shows nothing similar to `%e` that also does summing, but there is a generic `%(expression)`, with no explanation.

What `%(expression)` would give me output like the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that `%(expression)` is not a function which is passed any arguments, but the `(point)` is set to the current headline as it is processed, so you can write something like:

```
(org-agenda-prefix-format " %e %(or (org-entry-get (point) "Effort") "0:00") ")
```

...and the reported effort should agree with `%e`.

Now, `org-entry-get` does support searching ***up*** the hierarchy if the property is not set on the current item, but what's required is gathering ***all*** the properties ***down*** the hierarchy, so we can sum up the effort.

Here's a first go:

```
(defun my-org-entry-get-subtree (property)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (save-match-data
        (cl-loop while (re-search-backward org-heading-regexp nil t)
                 collect (org-entry-get (point) property))))))
```

Which can be used to sum the effort:

```
(defun my-org-effort-sum-current-item ()
  (org-minutes-to-hh:mm-string
    (cl-loop for minutes in (my-org-entry-get-subtree "Effort")
             sum (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (or minutes "0:00")))))
```

Problem: if you have a TODO with 3 sub-TODOs each with one hour of effort, and the you complete one sub-TODO, the sum remaining effort is 2 hours. But the above code includes the effort from the item in the DONE state, miss-stating 3 hours.

We must match only the items in the subtree which are in the TODO state:

```
(defun my-org-effort-sum-current-item-in-state (state)
  (org-minutes-to-hh:mm-string
    (cl-loop for minutes in (my-org-entry-subtree-in-state-get state "Effort")
             sum (org-hh:mm-string-to-minutes (or minutes "0:00")))))

(defun my-org-entry-subtree-in-state-get (state property)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (save-match-data
        (cl-loop while (re-search-backward org-heading-regexp nil t)
                 when (string-equal state (org-get-todo-state))
                 collect (org-entry-get (point) property))))))
```

Add this to the `org-agenda-prefix-format`:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" "My TODOs"
         ((tags-todo "mytag"
                     ((org-agenda-prefix-format "[%(my-org-effort-sum-current-item-in-state "TODO")] ")
                      (org-tags-match-list-sublevels t)))))))
```

...and you end up with something like this:

```
Projects
[3:00] TODO Some Project Task
[1:00] TODO Sub-task A
[1:00] TODO Sub-task B
[1:00] TODO Sub-task C
```

*(see [this other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/org-agenda-tags-todo-hierarchy-weirdness/9792) for how to get the sub-tasks to indent)*