# Is there a good way to see accumulated time over several org files using org-mode time tracking?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-mode for time tracking and can calculate the overall time with C-c C-x d. Is there a good way to show total time spent over several org-mode files (I tend to have separate projects in separate files)?

Answer (score 5):

In the agenda, hit `R` to add a "clock report" at the bottom, which summarises time spent on tasks by the org file they're in, as well as shows the total time.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ryan says, what you want is a clock table. The key is that the clock table can include several files. For example:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 4 :scope ("todo.org""journal.org") :block today
#+END:
```

If you C-c C-c on that line, it'll generate a clocktable that sums time spent across the files "todo.org" and "journal.org". Use :maxlevel to specify how detailed you want the output to be (summarized at the top level of each file? summaries for each headline? Summaries for each headline at depth 2? Etc.). But you'll get a total summed across all files at the top regardless.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [custom agenda command](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) to assemble arbitrary tasks from various files.

You then have a couple of ways of showing the clocking information:

1. A [custom org-agenda-prefix-format](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/org-agenda-todo-effort-rollup)
2. Switching to [column-view](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-view.html#Column-view) and using a format something like:

   ```
   (setq org-columns-default-format
         "%TODO %70ITEM(Task) %8Effort(Effort){:} %8CLOCKSUM{:} %8CLOCKSUM_T(Today){:} %CLOSED")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the Agenda's clockreport, you can drop [inline clocktables](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) in to your Org files, which is nice if you're looking for something more static than what an Agenda will generate.