# How to limit exported column view to a filtered subset of your headings?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I have a big org-mode file using tags and `TODO` keywords and properties. I would like to display a summary of "Effort" estimates **on
subsets** of the headings **with sums as we go up in the section hierarchy**.

Columnview is perfect for the summing part, except it lacks any means to filter headings.

And clock table could display `Effort` estimates (if listed in `:properties`) and filter heading appropriately but won't sum `Effort` estimate up along the heading hierarchy, and actually do not display any heading without CLOCK set.

Any hints on how I could achieve this ?

**EDIT:** I managed to do this thanks to org-babel and some external python code, but that's awfully complex.

Comment: Could you please post your org-babel/python-based solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tags-todo` query to select a subset of headings by tag, and `org-agenda-prefix-format` to show the effort with the headline.

You need to work a little bit harder for the effort roll-up in parent headlines - here's one way to do it:

[org-agenda todo effort rollup](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/org-agenda-todo-effort-rollup)