# Adding Headers to org-todo-list

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is it possible to set up org-todo-list to group TODOs under headers as they are  in my org-mode file?

Example org file structure:

```
* Project Name A
 ** TODOs
  *** TODO item 1
  *** TODO item 2
  *** TODO item 3
* Project Name B
 ** TODOs
   *** TODO item 1
   *** TODO item 2
   *** TODO item 3
```

And then in my org-agenda-list view it would show the todo's listed under their respective project names.  Could even have the "TODO" headings on there too, if there's not an easy way around that.

Edit: Just discovered org-todo-tree, which gets me pretty close.

Comment: Does this help? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5900/how-can-i-view-the-hierarchy-of-todo-keywords-in-org-agenda-mode/

Comment: Another option -- not directly answering your question -- is to add org tags to your projects.  The tags show up, which makes it easier to understand context