# Beginner: emacs org-agenda view: Beginner-friendly explanation of other answers on Emacs:SE

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

I am new to using Emacs and `org-mode`. In my current situation, I am using `org-agenda` view to overview and later exporting my TODO-tasks. However, when I view my TODOs with `org-agenda`, all TODO-marked headings have level 1 (well, are flattened to level 1). How can I preserve the level of TODO headings while viewing it in `org-agenda` and exporting it to another file?

For example:

`tasks.org`

```
* TODO Feed the cat
** TODO Wash dishes
* TODO Feed the dog
```

I get:

`exportedAgendaView.org`

```
* TODO Feed the cat
* TODO Wash dishes
* TODO Feed the dog
```

I have found these answers with identical issue:

[TODOs 1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5900/how-can-i-view-the-hierarchy-of-todo-keywords-in-org-agenda-mode)

[TODOs 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/org-agenda-tags-todo-hierarchy-weirdness?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But these answers are using terms (*breadcrumbs*) and functions (`org-agenda-prefix-format`) I dont know how to find or use. If I try to simply copy-paste code from accepted answer in [TODOs 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/org-agenda-tags-todo-hierarchy-weirdness?noredirect=1&lq=1) to `config.el`; I get no change in the `org-agenda` view or in the exported file.
Is this achievable? And could required steps be explained in beginner-friendly terms?

Final note: I am using Doom Emacs "distribution", if that is a factor.

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Regards, Tomas

**EDIT**

How am I getting `org-agenda` view and export to file:

In Doom Emacs (I hope that regular Emacs use same functions, I translate keyboard shortcuts to Emacs functions as much as I am able):

First I use `M-x org-agenda`, then in minibuffer I choose another keybinding - `t`, listed as "List of all TODO entries" (I think it is global TODO-list). This buffer (agenda view?) I am exporting with `org-agenda-write` (standard keybinding could be `C-x C-w`).
Is that correct way how to export todo-tasks?

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you go from  `tasks.org` to the agenda and to  `exportedAgendaView.org`?

Comment: @NickD I have edited the question with steps I am doing to export the todo-tasks to file.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions, in particular: (1) wrt what you're trying to do, and (2) how to understand some terms and functions you came across in other Q&A. Please pose separate questions: one question per post.

Comment: The files that can be produced from the agenda (see [Exporting Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Agenda-Views.html#Exporting-Agenda-Views) in the manual) are just lists of things: they are not Org mode files and they cannot be parsed. They are meant to be a way to take your agenda with you (by printing a text file  and taking the piece of paper with you; or by producing an HTML file that you can put on a server and visit later with the browser on your phone). So the answer to your first question is: you cannot preserve the lever structure because these are not Org mode files.

Comment: But this sounds like an XY question to me...

Comment: OK, I understand. But I honesly thought that eventhough those are two questions, that they are unseperable. @NickD OK, thank you for the commentary-answer. I try to find different way, and learn first some more basic-stuff in Emacs. Thank you for your help. The only think is that I really dont know what is an "XY question."

Comment: See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) on Wikipedia e.g.